# Access the pushbots REST Api from java

Tags: java, android, json, curl, pushbots

I am trying to send a push notification using pushbots. It is working when I use cURL but how could I achieve that from my java server?
The curl script that I would like to send is like that:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "x-pushbots-appid: 54cc0a511d0ab13c0528b459d" \
-H "x-pushbots-secret: 1444fe8be3324ff7128f25aa18cdee12" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"platform" : 1 , "msg" : "hi from Api" , "payload" : {"largeIcon":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2bMJQbKLNRQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAA_nc/SYnugOyXboE/s120-c/photo.jpga" }}' \
https://api.pushbots.com/push/all
```

Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");` is not an option because I have to do it responsive meaning I want to be able to change the `msg` json value. How could I achieve that?

Thanks for your time,
Vinci

Comment: You should post your best attempt at solving this using a standard Java REST library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you have to do is just HTTP requests. Sure you can achieve this with Java, and calling `curl` from Java isn't the good way to do it. The best way is to use some library for work with HTTP. For instance you can use [Apache HttpClient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient) which is pretty good. You can learn how to use this library [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) (don't be scared of the documentation size, you'll need only the basic functionality).

P.S. If I understand the question correctly, `Android` tag is not appropriate here.

**UPD**
Here is some code for your case (I didn't test it, but hope it'll help you):

```
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api.pushbots.com/push/all");
request.addHeader("x-pushbots-appid", "54cc...");
request.addHeader("x-pushbots-secret", "1444...");
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity("{your request body here}"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

You'll need to catch some exceptions also (isn't in this code) - `IOException`, `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: I will try this. My problem is that I am bad with http.

Comment: @Vinci I updated my answer with some sample code, try it. Ofc you need to add HttpClient jar to your classpath first (see link in answer).

Comment: It was actually not that hard (I already had some experience with apache HTTPClient)

Comment: With one of the last versions? There are many versions of `HttpClient` and they are very different (seems like `HttpClient` developers love to rewrite it again and again). Anyway glad it helped

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at `JBoss RESTEasy client`. As you can see from it's name it's designed to be used with REST services. I didn't like it very much when I used it, but maybe it'll be more suitable than `HttpClient` in your case.

Comment: Thanks again! But with the apache HttpClient it worked quite well